# How to get a buffer from an <audio> element?

Tags: html, html5-audio

There's a package I want to use called [react-waveform](https://github.com/klambycom/react-waveform) which will take a `buffer` object and display a visualization.

```
<Waveform buffer={buffer} width={720} color="cadetblue" />
```

The thing is, I need to get the buffer from an existing `<audio>` element. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
const audio = document.createElement('audio');

audio.src = '/link/to/mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', function () {
  const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  // source = MediaElementAudioSourceNode
  const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

  // ???
});
```

The Web Audio API documentation is massive, and I've been going through but have had no luck figuring out how to get the buffer object of an `<audio>` element. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: He seems to get an ArrayBuffer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11010338/1828637

Comment: I don't see an `<audio>` element anywhere in there.