# web audio analyze entire buffer

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I have the audio buffer of a prerecorded audio file in my application. 
I'm trying to get the frequency domain data of the ENTIRE audio track, this is what I've tried:

```
getAudioDataFromBuffer: function(buf){
    var src = g.audioContext.createBufferSource();
    src.buffer = buf;
    var anal = src.context.createAnalyser();
    src.connect(anal);
    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(buf.length);
    anal.fftSize = 2048;
    anal.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
    return dataArray;
},
```

But this only gives me an array full of zeros.

I need this to compare two audio tracks, one is prerecorded and the other is recorded in the application. I'm thinking I could measure the correlation between their frequency domains.

Comment: Just a note: don't shorten "analyze" :D

Comment: How do I get frequency domain data from the channel data? I tried measuring the correlations between the channel data directly but I didn't like the results. @Kaiido

Comment: @NoOorZ24 if that was the case, you also would never see `dic` as a variable name or the entire `std` library in C++ for that matter

Comment: I think its funny....

Answer (score 5):

I arrived to the solution seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699134/extracting-the-song-frequency-of-an-mp3-file-using-html5-web-audio-api) and [this discussion](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/303).

Basically you need to use an OfflineAudioContext. Here the code staring from an already loaded audio buffer:

```
var offline = new OfflineAudioContext(2, buffer.length ,44100);
var bufferSource = offline.createBufferSource();
bufferSource.buffer = buffer;

var analyser = offline.createAnalyser();
var scp = offline.createScriptProcessor(256, 0, 1);

bufferSource.connect(analyser);
scp.connect(offline.destination); // this is necessary for the script processor to start

var freqData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
scp.onaudioprocess = function(){
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData);
  console.log(freqData);
};

bufferSource.start(0);
offline.oncomplete = function(e){
  console.log('analysed');
};
offline.startRendering();
```

Comment: ScriptProcessor is being deprecated from Web Audio. Could you please update your answer to avoid using it?

Comment: @1valdis What would be an alternative?

Comment: I suppose [`AudioWorkletNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode) could work, ish, but that [isn't implemented in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1062849) and would be a hack anyway.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes, you're right with all of that, except there's a polyfill by Google which falls back to ScriptProcessor nodes where AudioWorklets aren't implemented. You may check it out: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/audioworklet-polyfill

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example using the latest version of the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API):

***Note: You need to start with an `audioBuffer`***.. you can get one using the new [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API):

```
const [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
const audioBuffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
```

Once you have the `audioBuffer`, you can access it's contents using `offlineAudioContext`:

```
const offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext(
    audioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
    audioBuffer.length,
    audioBuffer.sampleRate
  );
    
const bufferSourceNode = offlineAudioContext.createBufferSource();

bufferSourceNode.start(0);

offlineAudioContext
  .startRendering()
  .then(renderedBuffer => {

    const data = renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0);

    for (let i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i += 1) {

      // careful here, as you can hang the browser by logging this data
      // because 1 second of audio contains 22k ~ 96k samples!
      if (!(i % 1000) && i < 250000) console.log(data[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I found there are a couple of steps missing in the above: `bufferSourceNode.buffer=audioBuffer` and `bufferSourceNode.connect(offlineAudioContext.destination)` before `start`

Answer (score -1):

I think you need more something like

AudioBuffer.getChannelData()

Returns a Float32Array containing the PCM data associated with the channel, defined by the channel parameter (with 0 representing the first channel).

Lookup at Mozilla or W3C documentation.

Cheers

Kilian